# A clean and robust way to parse URL strings in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, url

I have a requirement to take a string that represents a URL that can be in many formats and standardise it so it conforms with the URL spec.

If the URL string does not have a scheme, or it has a scheme that is not 'http' or 'https', it should use a default scheme.

I wanted to use NSURLComponents but if a scheme is not provided it parses the host as a path

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"www.google.com.au"];
components.scheme = @"http";
NSLog(@"1: %@", components.path);
NSLog(@"2: %@", components.host);
NSLog(@"3: %@", components.string);

testtest[2619:869020] 1: www.google.com.au
testtest[2619:869020] 2: ((null))
testtest[2619:869020] 3: http:www.google.com.au <-- Invalid
```

Therefore I ended up with this category on NSString

```
#define DEFAULT_SCHEME @"http"

@implementation NSString (standardiseUrlFormat)

- (NSString*)standardiseUrlFormat {
    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:self];
    BOOL hasScheme = components.scheme != nil;

    // If no scheme or an invalid scheme is provided, default to http
    if (!hasScheme) {
        // We have to use string concatenation here because NSURLComponents will
        // put the hostname as the path if there is no scheme
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@", DEFAULT_SCHEME, self];
    }

    // Now we know that a scheme exists, check if it is a correct scheme
    if (![components.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] &&
        ![components.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        // Overwrite scheme if not supported
        components.scheme = DEFAULT_SCHEME;
    }

    return [components string];
}

@end
```

With the following output

```
NSLog(@"1: %@", [@"http://www.google.com" standardiseUrlFormat]);
NSLog(@"2: %@", [@"www.google.com" standardiseUrlFormat]);
NSLog(@"3: %@", [@"https://www.google.com" standardiseUrlFormat]);
NSLog(@"4: %@", [@"https://www.google.com/some_path" standardiseUrlFormat]);
NSLog(@"5: %@", [@"www.google.com/some_path" standardiseUrlFormat]);

testtest[7411:944022] 1: http://www.google.com
testtest[7411:944022] 2: http://www.google.com
testtest[7411:944022] 3: https://www.google.com
testtest[7411:944022] 4: https://www.google.com/some_path
testtest[7411:944022] 5: http://www.google.com/some_path
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner solution that doesn't use two methods (NSURLComponents and string concatenation) to construct the string?

Comment: That's pretty harsh. I doubt that changing mailto://example@example.com to http://example@example.com makes any sense at all. Or ftp, or file:// or basically anything other than http(s).

Comment: Thats true, but in this case it should be assumed that any input URL string was supposed to have a http or https scheme

Comment: Why not simply do a string-replace operation then? Look for the first "://" and replace what's before it with http (as long as it's not https). If not found, insert it at the front.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string concatenation at all. Use NSURLComponents to *form* the desired NSURL; that's what it's for. For example, if you don't like what the `scheme` is, *set* the `scheme` to what you do want.

**EDIT** I guess I was thinking that having detected that this is a hostless URL you would rejigger it by hand, e.g.

```
let s = "www.apple.com/whatever" as NSString
let arr = s.pathComponents
let c = NSURLComponents()
c.scheme = "http"
c.host = arr[0]
c.path = "/" + (Array(arr.dropFirst()) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("/")
```

But perhaps this can't be done, and the problem really is that a URL without a scheme is more or less not a URL.

Comment: The problem is that NSURLComponents doesn't parse URLs properly if they don't have a scheme. It puts the whole string as the path component and leaves the rest of the components as nil. 
Edit: I suppose I could create a new NSURLComponents object and construct it manually but I would have to do my own parsing to seperate the components which it much more complex.